# Parsing SRT file with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsdictionary

Text example:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,000
This is the first line

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,000
This is the second line

3
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:03,000
This is the last line
```

In JavaScript I would parse this with a regular expression certainly. I'm just wondering, is that the best way to do this in Obj C? I'm sure I could figure out a *way* to do this, but I'm wanting to do it an *appropriate* way.

I only need to know where to start and I'm happy to do the rest, but for understanding sake I'm going to end up with something like this (pseudo code):

```
NSDictionary
index -> [0-9]+
start -> hh:mm:ss,mmm
end -> hh:mm:ss,mmm
text -> one of the lines of text
```

In this case, I'd be parsing three entries into my dictionary.

Comment: By best way you mean efficient or easy-doable?

Comment: I err on the side of efficient, but I'll take whatever help I can get and just piece it together the way I see best.

Comment: Ok it's pretty clear, the only thing I don't understand is what you mean for "mmm", are these milliseconds?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Yep. I did **mmm** for milliseconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some background: I wrote a small app and created a file called stuff.srt containing your examples that resides in the bundle; hence, my means of accessing it.

This is just a quick and dirty thing, a proof-of-concept. Note that it doesn't check results. Real applications always check their results. As you can see, the work takes place in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method (I'm working in Mac OS X, not iOS).

**EDIT:**

It's been pointed out that the code as originally posted didn't handle multiple text lines correctly. To address this, I take advantage of the fact that [SRT files use CRLF as their line breaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip), and search for two occurrences of this sequence. I then change all occurrences of CRLF in the text string to spaces, based on what I observed [here](http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html). This doesn't account for leading or trailing spaces in each line of the text.

I changed the contents of the stuff.srt file to this:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,000
This is the first line
and it has a secondary line

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,000
This is the second line

3
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:03,000
This is the last line
and it has a secondary line too
```

and the code has been revised as follows (I also put everything into an @autoreleasepool directive; there might be a *lot* of autoreleased objects generated in the course of parsing the file!):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stuff" ofType:@"srt"];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            NSString *indexString;
            (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&indexString];

            NSString *startString;
            (void) [scanner scanUpToString:@" --> " intoString:&startString];

            // My string constant doesn't begin with spaces because scanners
            // skip spaces and newlines by default.
            (void) [scanner scanString:@"-->" intoString:NULL];

            NSString *endString;
            (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&endString];

            NSString *textString;
            // (void) [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&textString];
            // BEGIN EDIT
            (void) [scanner scanUpToString:@"\r\n\r\n" intoString:&textString];
            textString = [textString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@" "];
            // Addresses trailing space added if CRLF is on a line by itself at the end of the SRT file
            textString = [textString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            // END EDIT

            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        indexString, @"index",
                                        startString, @"start",
                                        endString , @"end",
                                        textString , @"text",
                                        nil];

            NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

The revised output looks like this:

```
2013-02-09 16:10:17.727 SRTFileScan[4846:303] {
    end = "00:00:01,000";
    index = 1;
    start = "00:00:00,000";
    text = "This is the first line and it has a secondary line";
}
2013-02-09 16:10:17.729 SRTFileScan[4846:303] {
    end = "00:00:02,000";
    index = 2;
    start = "00:00:01,000";
    text = "This is the second line";
}
2013-02-09 16:10:17.730 SRTFileScan[4846:303] {
    end = "00:00:03,000";
    index = 3;
    start = "00:00:02,000";
    text = "This is the last line and it has a secondary line too";
}
```

One other thing I learned from what I've read today: The SRT file format originated in France, and the comma seen in the input is the decimal separator used there.

Comment: I'm going to do an implementation very close to yours so I figure I'll give you the point and just put my personal solution into an edit to my questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful to me, but I noticed there's a problem on texts with more than one line. In that case the parsing is broken.

Comment: Hi, thanks for supporting multiple lines now, on my file I think I just have \n so probably I'm using a non standard .srt (The line break used is often the CR+LF pair). Then I would suggest to keep the "\n" instead of the space to preserve the multiline.

Comment: @EmanueleFumagalli That was something to which I had to pay attention; I originally had created my own file with the data provided by the OP, and I hadn't paid attention to the kind of line breaks used. Anyway, you're welcome, and thank you.

Comment: This post has been a great help @trudyscousin - one question. As you discussed, most subtitles seem to go with CRLF(\r\n) to break a line, but sometimes I come across just LF(\n) as EmanueleFumagalli mentioned. Would there be a way to integrate the two alternative approaches in this code?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt Haven't tried this myself, but: first record the current location of the scanner. Then, scan for \r\n\r\n. If that leads to scanner.isAtEnd == YES, then restore the scanner's location with the saved location, then scan for \n\n.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a sample code to parse subtitle files. Check the relevant part here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX/Listings/avsubtitleswriter_SubtitlesTextReader_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013409-avsubtitleswriter_SubtitlesTextReader_m-DontLinkElementID_5

Answer (score 0):

My suggest is to use a [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the second line. I would split that string in two strings (see componentsSeparatedByString: in [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)). This while reading the file line per line.

So the loop would be:

- If the file contains again data, read the next line;
- If the next line is a multiple of 4, allocate a new object. This object should be able to contain two dates, one integer and one string;
- If the next line is not a multiple of 4, read the line and assign it's value to the corresponding field.